# Pytorch problem testing CNN: RuntimeError: shape '[64, 1]' is invalid for input of size 1920

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, pytorch

Testing network:

```
 def test(args, model, device, test_loader):
           model.eval()
           total = 0
           test_loss = 0
           correct = 0
           with torch.no_grad():
           for batch_idx, batch in enumerate(test_loader):
               data = batch['image']
               target = batch['key_points']
               data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
               # data, target = Variable(data), Variable(target)
           # for data, target in test_loader:
           #     data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
           #     data, target = Variable(data), Variable(target)
                 data = data.unsqueeze(1).float() 

                 print('TESTING 1: Data and target shape: ', data.shape, ' 
                       ', target.shape)
                 output = model(data)
                 target = target.view(target.shape[0], -1)  

                 print('TESTING 2: Data and target shape: ', data.shape, ' 
                       ', target.shape)
                 # test_loss += F.nll_loss(output, target, 
                 reduction='sum').item()  # sum up batch loss orginal
                 test_loss = F.nll_loss(output, torch.max(target, 1)[1])
                  # test_loss += F.nll_loss(output, 
                  torch.max(target.float(), 1)[1], reduction='sum').item()

                   print('TESTING 3: Data and target shape: ', data.shape, 
                       ' ', target.shape)
                   # pred = output.max(1, keepdim=True)[1]  
                   pred = output.argmax(dim=1, keepdim=True)  # original

                   print('TESTING 4: Data and target shape: ', data.shape, 
                       ' ', target.shape)

                   correct += pred.eq(target.view_as(pred)).sum().item()   
                   print('TESTING last: Data and target shape: ', 
                   data.shape, ' ', target.shape)

                   test_loss /= len(test_loader.dataset)
                   print('\nTest set: Average loss: {:.4f}, Accuracy: 
                        {}/{} ({:.0f}%)\n'.format(
                         test_loss , correct, len(test_loader.dataset),
                         100. * correct / len(test_loader.dataset)))
```

I can run the training loop which is fine however when I try to run testing loop as well the training will only run 1 epoch and I get the following message.

> ```
> TESTING 1: Data and target shape:  torch.Size([64, 1, 96, 96])  
> torch.Size([64, 15, 2]) TESTING 2: Data and target shape: 
> torch.Size([64, 1, 96, 96])   torch.Size([64, 30]) 
> TESTING 3: Data and target shape:  torch.Size([64, 1, 96, 96])  
> torch.Size([64, 30])
> TESTING 4: Data and target shape:  torch.Size([64, 1, 96, 96])  
>  torch.Size([64, 30]) Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>  "/home/keith/PycharmProjects/FacialLandMarks/WorkOut.py", line 468, in <module>
>     main()   File "/home/keith/PycharmProjects/FacialLandMarks/WorkOut.py", line 463, in main
>     test(args, model, device, test_loader)   File "/home/keith/PycharmProjects/FacialLandMarks/WorkOut.py", line 380, in test
>     correct += pred.eq(target.view_as(pred)).sum().item()   
>  RuntimeError: shape '[64, 1]' is invalid for input of size 1920
>  Process finished with exit code 1
> ```

I have not been able to come across any helpful resources on-line or in a number of books I've purchased, on this specific problem, facial key point detection testing phase. I think problem is shown in error message(marked with comment) or with my data.  I am using a separate set of test images with training key points csv file.  As you can see I have printed out shape of data throughout the testing phase.
Any help or useful links always appreciated. Thank you

When I use pycharm debugger and view breakpoints when I get to the line of code below:

```
pred = output.max(1, keepdim=True)[1]
```

Then pred tensor changes to this:

```
tensor([[29],
        [29],
        [29],
        [29],
        [29],
        [29],
        [29],
        [29],

         ...
        [29],
        [29],
        [29],
        [29],
        [29],
        [29],
        [29]], device='cuda:0')
```

Comment: Thought I would add this link for anyone having similar problem:  https://medium.com/@uijaz59/dog-breed-classification-using-pytorch-207cf27c2031

Comment: I took out this line and the test method runs: 'correct += pred.eq(target.view_as(pred)).sum().item()'   I think i right in saying this is only used for image classification so if I replace this with something else it should work properly then I can actually get into the fun stuff.  Anyone any ideas?  Found this book quite useful: Deep Learning with Pytorch:  Guide for Beginners and Intermediate, Jerry N. P.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the shape of ´pred´ is [64,1] whereas the shape of `target` is [64,30]. Now if you're calling `target.view_as(pred)` you're trying to view `target` in the same shape as `pred`, but `target` has 64*30=1920 entries, whereas `pred` only has 64, so that's where the error is coming from.

Are you sure that your targets are correct? Because you're predicting a 1-dimensional output, but trying to compare to a 30-dimensional target.